# Google maps water color style

Tags: google-maps, url

Cheers.

I need get map via google maps api and override water color with hex. Now my api url looks like that:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.85589,27.45345&zoom=16&size=512x512&style=feature:water|color:#0099dd

But water doesn't change color. If i'm replace #0099dd with red, that's works fine.

I thinks there the problem with "#" symbol. I tried to replace that with %25, but it's still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro).  Hex colors are preceded with `0x`.  This works for me:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.85589,27.45345&zoom=16&size=512x512&style=feature:water|color:0x0099dd

Comment: Brilliant!
My bad, i'm doesn't notice that part.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Static Maps expects colours formatted as 0x0099dd.

It should work if you change your url to:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.85589,27.45345&zoom=16&size=512x512&style=feature:water|color:0x0099dd

Source: [Google Static Maps Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#StyledMaps)